# Angular 2 error: Can't bind to 'innerhtml' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Using angular 2 to bind a raw html inside a DIV

Version:
Angular 2 "2.0.0-rc.1"

References on index.html:

```
<script src="~/lib/ng/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/zone.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/ng/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
```

index HTML:

```
...

<div  [innerHTML]="name"></div>

...
```

Javascript:

```
ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(        
    ng.core
    .Component(
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: <div  [innerHTML]="name"></div>
    )
    .Class(
        constructor: function()
        {
            name = "<div>Testing</div>"
        }
    )
)
```

Error:

> > EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'innerhtml' since it
> >     isn't a known native property ("
> >
> > ## # 1
> >     {{ name }}
> >
> > ][innerhtml]="name">        
> >              "): QuestOperationComponent@4:8
>
> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: Can't
>   bind to 'innerhtml' since it isn't a known native property ("
>
> ## # 1 {{ name }}
>
> ][innerhtml]="name">             "): QuestOperationComponent@4:8

I already tried:

```
[innerHtml] 
[innerHTML] 
[inner-Html] 
[inner-html]
```

Comment: `[innerHTML]` is the correct syntax as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding). I tested it with r.c.3. I know you already tried, but just to be sure, can you try again with that syntax and update the error message?

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me

```
<div innerHTML="{{name}}"></div>.
```